# How to update fields dynamically in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Set demo1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Set demo2</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Set demo3</button>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
```

This is the markup I have. I am trying to use just one function to update the `<p>` tags individually.

Example Scenario: Clicking `Set demo1` button will only update the `<p>` which has `id="demo1"` but **with only one function**.
Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following approach. Clicking on each `button` will affect corresponding `p` element.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
    Array.from(elems).forEach(v => v.addEventListener('click', function(){
      var index = this.innerHTML.match(/\d+/)[0];
      var elem = document.getElementById('demo'+index);
      // logic
      elem.style.color = 'red';  // just an example
    }));
```

```html
<button class='btn'>Set demo1</button>
<button class='btn'>Set demo2</button>
<button class='btn'>Set demo3</button>

<p id="demo1">1</p>
<p id="demo2">2</p>
<p id="demo3">3</p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please explain the 3rd and 4th line from the js part?

Answer (score 0):

If you change your markup slightly so that each button has a `data-target` attribute, then it can be easily done.

HTML:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" data-target="#demo1">Set demo1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()" data-target="#demo2">Set demo2</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()" data-target="#demo3">Set demo3</button>
```

JS

```
function myFunction() {
    var pTag = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('data-target'));
    pTag.textContent = "Hello world"; // whatever you would like
}
```